# Se puede hacer un INSERT en un SELECT PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql, insert, table

que tal!
Tengo un requerimiento, el cual me dice que necesito hacer una consulta de una tabla que al mismo tiempo inserte esa consulta en otra tabla. Para ser mas especifico les doy detalles de la tabla;
[image: Columnas de la tabla]

En la tabla anterior 'suplementos', tengo los campos Id, Date, Value y Parameter, para mi consulta necesito obtener la suma total de todos los 'value' en un rango de fecha 'date' determinado, y dicho resultado insertarlo en otra tabla 'suplementos_total' la cual tiene las mismas columnas de la tabla anterior.

El objetivo de esto es sacar un total diario, debido a que los registros se guardan en la tabla 'suplementos' cada 15min, no estoy muy seguro si se puede hacer todo esto en una sola consulta o habría que utilizar una función o trigger PostgreSQL, la verdad no soy muy diestro en SQL, además de que no se me permite hacer Vistas.

Si tienen alguna idea, me ayudaria bastante!
Salud2

Comment: algo asi como un insert into tabla select....???

Comment: Algo mas como; `Select x1,x2 From tablax Where conditions`, y meter el Insert dentro de ese Select. Ya que necesito consultar primero y luego de ese resultado insertar en otra tabla.

Comment: ehhhh... pero la sentencia inesrt into hace eso.. consulta y luego inserta.. cual seria la diferencia????

Comment: Bueno si funciona por mi esta bien, soy muy novato en esto del SQL, si puedes darme un ejemplo de lo que escribí en la pregunta seria genial!

Comment: Aclara cual es tu select asi te decimos como seria el insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu estás intentando algo como esto no ??
Se puedes hacer un select dentro del insert, 
solo debes tener claro que valor estás tomando para la fila, y debes pasarlo bien.

```
INSERT INTO `nueva`(`valor`) 
VALUES (
    (SELECT SUM(v.valor) FROM valores v))
```

Resultado: https://i.gyazo.com/a2bb48fc52e2cc0ec6e92db2b471a058.png
Tabla valores mia: https://i.gyazo.com/90d91bfa275152c4412ed221a9165d3c.png

Comment: Muchas gracias! era lo que buscaba, logre hacer el mío propio a partir de este.

Comment: Excelente !!! espero te sirva de mucho